# How to add text and delete text using GUI in Java

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jbutton, actionlistener

I am creating a dumb phone (like old traditional phone) and I'm using GUI programming. I need help with dialing the numbers. I don't know how to get the numbers to pop up on the display and stay there, and also use the delete button to delete the numbers that is up on the display too. I will post a youtube link so you can see a sample run.

I am currently stuck on passing the text from the button of each number that should display the number, however it's displaying the text of the button. I also, don't know how to keep the number there when other buttons are pressed without it being reset.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DumbPhone extends JFrame
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final int WIDTH = 300;
private static final int HEIGHT = 500;

private static final String CALL_BUTTON_TEXT = "Call";
private static final String TEXT_BUTTON_TEXT = "Text";
private static final String DELETE_BUTTON_TEXT = "Delete";
private static final String CANCEL_BUTTON_TEXT = "Cancel";
private static final String SEND_BUTTON_TEXT = "Send";
private static final String END_BUTTON_TEXT = "End";
private static final String CALLING_DISPLAY_TEXT = "Calling...";
private static final String TEXT_DISPLAY_TEXT = "Enter text...";
private static final String ENTER_NUMBER_TEXT = "Enter a number...";

private JTextArea display;

private JButton topMiddleButton;
private JButton topLeftButton;
private JButton topRightButton;

private JButton[] numberButtons;

private JButton starButton;
private JButton poundButton;

private boolean isNumberMode = true;

private String lastPressed = "";
private int lastCharacterIndex = 0;
private Date lastPressTime;

public DumbPhone()
{
    setTitle("Dumb Phone");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    createContents();
    setVisible(true);
    topLeftButton.setEnabled(false);
}
private void createContents()
{
    //create JPanel, and JTextArea display
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,3));
    display = new JTextArea();
    display.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 80));
    display.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 32));
    display.setLineWrap(true);
    display.setEnabled(false);
    panel.add(display);
    //create JButtons
    topLeftButton = new JButton(DELETE_BUTTON_TEXT);
    topMiddleButton = new JButton((CALL_BUTTON_TEXT));
    topRightButton = new JButton((TEXT_BUTTON_TEXT));
    numberButtons = new JButton[10];
    numberButtons[1] = new JButton("<html><center>1<br></center></html>");
    numberButtons[2] = new JButton("<html><center>2<br>ABC</center></html>");
    numberButtons[3] = new JButton("<html><right>3<br>DEF</right></html>");
    numberButtons[4] = new JButton("<html><center>4<br>GHI</center></html>");
    numberButtons[5] = new JButton("<html><center>5<br>JKL</center></html>");
    numberButtons[6] = new JButton("<html><center>6<br>MNO</center></html>");
    numberButtons[7] = new JButton("<html><center>7<br>PQRS</center></html>");
    numberButtons[8] = new JButton("<html><center>8<br>TUV</center></html>");
    numberButtons[9] = new JButton("<html><center>9<br>WXYZ</center></html>");
    numberButtons[0] = new JButton("<html><center>0<br>space</center></html>");

    poundButton = new JButton("#");
    starButton = new JButton("*");
    //add JButtons to buttons JPanel
    panel.add(topLeftButton);
    panel.add(topMiddleButton);
    panel.add(topRightButton);
    panel.add(numberButtons[1]);
    panel.add(numberButtons[2]);
    panel.add(numberButtons[3]);
    panel.add(numberButtons[4]);
    panel.add(numberButtons[5]);
    panel.add(numberButtons[6]);
    panel.add(numberButtons[7]);
    panel.add(numberButtons[8]);
    panel.add(numberButtons[9]);
    panel.add(starButton);
    panel.add(numberButtons[0]);
    panel.add(poundButton);
    //add Listener instance (inner class) to buttons
    topLeftButton.addActionListener(new Listener());
    topMiddleButton.addActionListener(new Listener());
    topRightButton.addActionListener(new Listener());
    //JButton[] array = new JButton[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberButtons.length; i++)
    {
        numberButtons[i].addActionListener(new Listener());
        numberButtons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
    }
        starButton.addActionListener(new Listener());
        poundButton.addActionListener(new Listener());
    //add display and buttons to JFrame
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

private class Listener implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == topLeftButton)
        {
                if(lastPressTime == null)
                {
                    display.setText(ENTER_NUMBER_TEXT);
                }
                else
                {
                    topLeftButton.setEnabled(true);
                    lastCharacterIndex--;
                    lastPressed = lastPressTime.toString();
                }
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == topMiddleButton)
        {
            if(lastPressTime == null || lastCharacterIndex == 0)
            {
                display.setText(ENTER_NUMBER_TEXT);
            }
            else
            {
                display.setText(CALLING_DISPLAY_TEXT);
            }
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == topRightButton)
        {
            if(lastPressTime == null || lastCharacterIndex == 0)
            {
                display.setText(TEXT_DISPLAY_TEXT);
            }
            else
            {
                display.setText(CALLING_DISPLAY_TEXT);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            topLeftButton.setEnabled(true);
            if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton)
            {
                //String text = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();
                display.setText(lastPressed + " f" + numberButtons[lastCharacterIndex].getText());
            }
        }
        Date currentPress = new Date();

        long currentTime = currentPress.getTime();
        if(lastPressTime != null)
        {
            //long lastPressTime = lastPressTime.getTime();
            //subtract lastPressTime from currentPress time to find amount of time elapsed since last button pressed.
        }
        lastPressTime = currentPress;
        String buttonLetters = ""; // Parse Letter from button (e.g "abc").
        //update lastCharacterIndex.
        lastCharacterIndex++;
        lastCharacterIndex = lastCharacterIndex % buttonLetters.length();
    }
}
```

for example, if I push the button 2, instead of giving me "2", it will give me < html>< center>2
ABC < / center >< / html >

Therefore, I need help with

1. Having the numberButtons, when pushed to show the numbers that were pushed.
2. Be able to delete those numbers.

Here is the link to the sample run: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evmGWlMSqqg&feature=youtu.be

Try starting the video 20 seconds in.

Comment: `display.setText` will replace the existing text.  My "general" recommendation is to use a `StringBuilder` as your primary buffer.  This way you can easily append and remove characters from it and then would pass this to `display.setText`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Where in my code will I put in StringBuilder?

Comment: You would make it an instance field.  When the user presses a button, you would update it based on your rules and requirements and then pass it to `display.setText`

Comment: @MadProgrammer What do you mean by an instance field? I don't know what that is...

Comment: `private JTextArea display;` is an instance field - it's a variable, define at the class level, but which requires an instance of the class to be accessible, as apposed to those declared `static`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I need help on the text box on having it keep the numbers up and not reset...

Comment: Simple append (or remove) characters from a `StringBuilder` then apply that to the textfield, `setText` is going to replace the text with what ever you give it, so you might as well maintain the buffer separately (ie in the `StringBuilder`) and then set the text of the field as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to delete the number, you can use the labelname.setText("")

Answer (score 0):

At a basic level, you simply want to maintain the "numbers" separately from the UI.  This commonly known as a "model". The model lives independently of the UI and allows the model to be represented in any number of possible ways based on the needs of the application.

In your case, you could use a linked list, array or some other simple sequential based list, but the easiest is probably to use a `StringBuilder`, as it provides the functionality you require (append and remove) and can make a `String` very simply.

So, the first thing you need to do is create an instance of model as an instance level field;

```
private StringBuilder numbers = new StringBuilder(10);
```

this will allow the buffer to be accessed any where within the instance of the class.

Then you need to update the model...

```
else
{
    topLeftButton.setEnabled(true);
    if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton)
    {
        String text = numberButtons[lastCharacterIndex].getText();
        numbers.append(text);
    }
}
```

To remove the last character you can simply use something like...

```
if (numbers.length() > 0) {
    numbers.deleteCharAt(numbers.length() - 1);
}
```

Then, when you need to, you update the UI using something like...

```
display.setText(numbers.toString());
```

Now, this is just basic concepts, you will need to take the ideas and apply it to your code base

Comment: I know a few more details filled in